Shared metrics for prometheus exporter app
I am writing a custom exporter with a number of different endpoints with different metrics to be scraped.
http.HandleFunc("/metrics", WrappedPromHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/metrics/access_points", apExportHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/metrics/stations", stationExportHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/metrics/shapers", shaperExportHandler)

As we all know, the default gatherer already has some instrumented metrics
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the pause duration of garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 3.9025e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 8.5927e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0.000121653
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0.000165482
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.004857846
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.018503631
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 97
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 7
# HELP go_info Information about the Go environment.
# TYPE go_info gauge
go_info{version="go1.22.1"} 1
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes Number of bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_alloc_bytes 3.3005208e+07
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total Total number of bytes allocated, even if freed.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total counter
go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total 9.61707112e+08
# HELP go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes Number of bytes used by the profiling bucket hash table.
# TYPE go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes 7770
# HELP go_memstats_frees_total Total number of frees.
# TYPE go_memstats_frees_total counter
go_memstats_frees_total 1.4088579e+07
# HELP go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for garbage collection system metadata.
# TYPE go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes 3.889176e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes Number of heap bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes 3.3005208e+07
# HELP go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes Number of heap bytes waiting to be used.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes 6.3209472e+07
# HELP go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes Number of heap bytes that are in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes 4.0484864e+07
# HELP go_memstats_heap_objects Number of allocated objects.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_objects gauge
go_memstats_heap_objects 838965
# HELP go_memstats_heap_released_bytes Number of heap bytes released to OS.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_released_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_released_bytes 3.1817728e+07
# HELP go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes Number of heap bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes 1.03694336e+08
# HELP go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds Number of seconds since 1970 of last garbage collection.
# TYPE go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds gauge
go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds 1.7187610046051216e+09
# HELP go_memstats_lookups_total Total number of pointer lookups.
# TYPE go_memstats_lookups_total counter
go_memstats_lookups_total 0
# HELP go_memstats_mallocs_total Total number of mallocs.
# TYPE go_memstats_mallocs_total counter
go_memstats_mallocs_total 1.4927544e+07
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mcache structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes 19200
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mcache structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes 31200
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mspan structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes 881600
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mspan structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes 1.5504e+06
# HELP go_memstats_next_gc_bytes Number of heap bytes when next garbage collection will take place.
# TYPE go_memstats_next_gc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_next_gc_bytes 6.64884e+07
# HELP go_memstats_other_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for other system allocations.
# TYPE go_memstats_other_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_other_sys_bytes 3.182478e+06
# HELP go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by the stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes 1.14688e+06
# HELP go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system for stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes 1.14688e+06
# HELP go_memstats_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_sys_bytes 1.1350224e+08
# HELP go_threads Number of OS threads created.
# TYPE go_threads gauge
go_threads 18
# HELP process_cpu_seconds_total Total user and system CPU time spent in seconds.
# TYPE process_cpu_seconds_total counter
process_cpu_seconds_total 11.45
# HELP process_max_fds Maximum number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_max_fds gauge
process_max_fds 1.048576e+06
# HELP process_open_fds Number of open file descriptors.
# TYPE process_open_fds gauge
process_open_fds 10
# HELP process_resident_memory_bytes Resident memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_resident_memory_bytes gauge
process_resident_memory_bytes 8.3705856e+07
# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1.71875967497e+09
# HELP process_virtual_memory_bytes Virtual memory size in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_bytes 1.336455168e+09
# HELP process_virtual_memory_max_bytes Maximum amount of virtual memory available in bytes.
# TYPE process_virtual_memory_max_bytes gauge
process_virtual_memory_max_bytes 1.8446744073709552e+19
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight Current number of scrapes being served.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight gauge
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight 1
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total Total number of scrapes by HTTP status code.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total counter
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200"} 13
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="500"} 0
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="503"} 0

My issue is (I believe) that because I am using a new registry and collector for each of the routes, these metrics don't appear to be updating correctly when any of the other endpoints are called. For example, calling /metrics/access_points doesn't update the metric promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200"}
I would like these metrics to be linked to the other endpoints, but I'm not sure how to do that. Below is my function for one of the other endpoints to illustrate how the metrics are served
    slog.Debug("Serving exporter metrics", slog.Any("url", r.URL))
    metrics, err := exporter.ApExport()

    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("Error exporting metrics",
            slog.Any("error", err),
            slog.Any("url", r.URL),
        )
        http.Error(rw, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    // Serve metrics
    registry := prometheus.NewRegistry()
    collector := common.NewCollector(metrics)
    registry.MustRegister(collector)
    h := promhttp.HandlerFor(registry, promhttp.HandlerOpts{})
    h.ServeHTTP(rw, r)

}

I've attempted the method below, which had the effect of showing the go metrics along with the generated metrics (which I don't want, I want them to stay at /metrics), but the values weren't consistent between the two different endpoints for status 200 metrics anyway. I'm not convinced these were shared metrics between the endpoints
metrics, err := exporter.ApExport()
registry := prometheus.NewRegistry()
collector := common.NewCollector(metrics)
gatherers := prometheus.Gatherers{
        prometheus.DefaultGatherer, 
        registry,
    }
h := promhttp.HandlerFor(gatherers, promhttp.HandlerOpts{})
h.ServeHTTP(rw, r)

